# Convert html 5 to PDF in MVC 3

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, pdf, svg, highcharts

I have created an application in asp.net MVC 3, I used `highchart.js` for rendering chart(stacked column) in view and its output is coming as `svg`.
 I need to convert this chart page into PDF file. I tried `iTextSharp` but its not showing the chart page content.

Is there anyway to `convert html 5 to PDF`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use a webkit component such as HTM2PDF to render HTML to PDF - see an explanation here:

[Highcharts to PDF with Webkit](http://www.htm2pdf.co.uk/highcharts-to-pdf-with-webkit/)

Answer (score 2):

ExpertPDF is a nuget package you can install.  For it to work without putting text over your pdf, you'll have to purchase a license.  It can handle svg.

http://www.html-to-pdf.net/ExpertPDF-HtmlToPdf-Converter.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to convert svg to image then you can use PhantomJS (headless webkit browser). With help of PhantomJS you can render svg and make screenshot. Then you can create a PDF and insert that image into it.

Also you can Aspose.Pdf for converting svg into PDF directly. See: http://www.aspose.com/.net/pdf-component.aspx (it's a paid component!)